# Is polling on a ZMQ router socket threadsafe?

Tags: zeromq

I have multiple threads interacting with the same ZeroMQ router socket (bad idea, I know).  I manage thread safety with locks on all sends and receives.

Do I also need to lock polling or is this relatively benign operation threadsafe?

Comment: You'll get a better response from the ZMQ mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

I think using polling alleviates any need for multithreading. You can pick up events as they come in using the poll loop on one thread and then distribute those events if you wish to other threads for processing. This way you don't need to share the socket.

Comment: But whatever you do, don't share the socket among threads however much lock.